# i18n - Internacionalização Java - Mensagem de validação de entidades

Tags: java, spring, i18n, internacionalização

Tenho uma aplicação `Spring Boot` onde estou desenvolvendo um sistema `Web` utilizando `Thymeleaf`. O sistema tem a funcionalidade de tradução de acordo com o idioma do usuário, porém, ao utilizar na entidade, através das `annotations` de validações, por exemplo, o `@Size` com `min` e `max` não é passado para a entidade. Gostaria de saber qual a solução para este problema. Ressalto que, no demais, a tradução funciona corretamente.

Segue a baixo mais detalhes:
Entidade:

```
@Column(name = "corporate_name", length = 255, nullable = false)
@Size(min = 3, max = 255, message = "{entities.messages.size.corporate-name}")
protected String corporateName;

@Column(name = "fantasy_name", nullable = false)
@Size(min = 3, max = 255, message = "{entities.messages.size.fantasy-name}")
protected String fantasyName;
```

A mensagem no arquivo de tradução:

> entities.messages.size.corporate-name=The corporate name must be between {0} and {1} characters.

> entities.messages.size.fantasy-name=The fantasy name must be between {0} and {1} characters.

Até onde havia pesquisado e entendido sobre este assunto, os valores mínimo e máximo da `annotation` `Size`, deveria ser automaticamente substituídos pelos respectivos valores `{0}` e `{1}` da mensagem, porém, ao realizar os testes, é exibido 0 e 1 como pode ser visto abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O esperado era que fosse exibido, por exemplo, a mensagem:

> The corporate name must be between 3 and 255 characters.

Comment: Será que no seu arquivo de mensagem vc não tem de estruturar da seguinte forma: `Size.MinhaEntidade.meuAtributo=Exam title must contain between {2} and {1} characters.`? Olhei essa referência: https://dzone.com/articles/exception-handling-and-i18n-on-spring-boots-apis-p

Comment: @Fabio Souza, eu respondi com o mesmo conteúdo da outra resposta negativada, porém com links de documentações. Depois que eu vi que você comentou que não funcionou corretamente! O que me faz pensar se não é algum erro de configuração do seu projeto. Eu tenho uma API que atualmente utiliza {min} e {max} com mensagens customizadas e funciona 100%. Poderia por gentileza descrever os imports da classe e a estrutura do projeto onde está seu arquivo de internacionalização, versão do Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, qualquer `@Configuration` para carregar os bundles, e Validator que está utilizando?

Comment: @nullptr, achei a definição https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=7.0#_examples você está correto há mesmo esse comportamento por parte da anotação `@Size`. O erro é meu.

Comment: Incluí um projeto com um exemplo funcionando [em meu github](https://github.com/ngueno/stackoverflow-examples/tree/main/spring-boot-size-validator-custom-message), adicionei também testes unitários para validação da mensagem de retorno.

Comment: Ainda suspeito que seja algum problema de configuração no projeto do @Fabio

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei a solução definitiva para o meu problema.

Acontece que, quando eu criei o `@Bean` `MessageSource` deveria ter deixado o `setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage` como `false` (ou não tivesse incluído a linha, pois o padrão é false)  e havia deixado como `true`.

Para corrigir, bastou alterar de
`messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);` para `messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);` ou remover a linha.
Segue:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages/i18n");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
    final LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(this.messageSource());
    return bean;
}
```

Um outro ponto, que deixo como observação, é que os parâmetros como {0} e {1} por exemplo, não funcionaram de maneira adequada, tendo que alterar para {min} e {max} como pode ser visto abaixo:
`entities.messages.size.corporate-name=The corporate name must be between {min} and {max} characters.`
Agradeço a todos que me auxiliaram.

Answer (score -3):

Bom dia! Tenta alterar para:

```
entities.messages.size.corporate-name=The corporate name must be between {min} and {max} characteres. 
entities.messages.size.fantasy-name=The fantasy name must be between {min} and {min} characteres.
```

Comment: Já tentei, ele remove as chaves e deixa 'min' e 'max', ficando assim:
```The corporate name must be between min and max characters```